# Replace weird or special character in a string

Tags: excel, vba, character-encoding, vb6

I'm trying to convert a Excel file into a SQL query. My problem is that there are special characters in the file I was given. I cant replace them CTRL+H because they dont show at all in the Excel file. When I write my query(either in utf8 or ANSI), they show. With Ultra-Edit, they show as HEX C2 92. With Notepad++ in utf8, they show as PU2. In ANSI, they show as Â’. I suspect it's an apostrophe. This is a french file by the way.

So far I tried to put it in a string and do these operations, but nothing worked.

```
Dim Line as String

Line = Wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(LineNo, ColNo)

Line = Replace(Line, "Â’", "''")
Line = Replace(Line, "’", "''")
Line = Replace(Line, "Â", "''")
Line = Replace(Line, Chr(194) & Chr(146), "''") 'decimal value of C2 92
Line = Replace(Line, Chr(146) & Chr(194), "''") 'inverted decimal value of C2 92
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is the data in your database encoded?  If you replace "special" characters in your SQL will that cause problems?

Comment: The `’` seems to be ChrW(8192).

Comment: You have a Unicode character "PRIVATE USE TWO" I don't know if this helps you, but more information can be found here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm

Comment: Can you share an example of the Excel file, and of how it **should** look in SQL?  It's a lot easier to others to help out if they don't have to speculate what the start and end points look like.  What purpose do these "invisible characters" serve in SQL (that isn't necessary in Excel)?  Where did this "weird" Excel source file come from?  Another application?

Comment: I'll bet @Jeeped didn't actually have that Unicode i.d. memorized.  I bet we can find out how he knew that if we Google it.  ;)

Comment: @ashleedawg - in xl2013 or higher paste that `’` character into A1 then in B1 use `=unicode(a1)`. I had copied the char directly from the OP's code block. [edit] weird. I just redid it and now it shows 8217.

Comment: @Jeeped - I hope you realize my comment was meant as a hint to the OP that some helpful exisiting hints & answers are not hard to find at this point?  Kind of meant as a tongue-in-cheek silent +1.  :-)  I'm experimenting with ways of politely pointing certain new-member Q's to existing A's. (I enjoy "giving back" by helping other newbies but I'm now seeing a pattern that veterans such as yourself can become frustrated with at times...)

Comment: @ashleedawg - sorry for stepping in it. I completely agree and have adopted a similar attitude myself.

Comment: @Jeeped - np, you don't have to be sorry for stepping in when I'm using your comment as my "prop"

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to eliminate various junk characters, try to focus on keeping only the good ones.  Say we know valid characters are upper and lower case letters, numbers, and the underscore.  This code will keep only the good ones:

```
Public Function KeepOnlyGood(s As String) As String
    Dim CH As String, L As Long, i As Long
    KeepOnlyGood = ""
    L = Len(s)
        For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9a-zA-Z]" Or CH = "_" Then
            KeepOnlyGood = KeepOnlyGood & CH
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

If you want to replace junk with a *space*, the code can be modified to do just that.